# Finding item with condition in array mongodb / mongooose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an order schema which includes:

```
cart.items: [{
  isPremium: true
}]
```

That is, `cart.items` is a list of objects with certain properties, one of which is `isPremium`.

I want to query for all orders which have an item which has `isPremium` true.

How can I do this, do I need to use `$elemMatch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Find query, it will search the items whose isPremium field is true

```
  db.order.find({'cart.items.isPremium':true})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.cart.find({"items.isPremium": true})
```

[Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) to the documentation

Comment: The collection is called orders though.

Comment: I thought cart is the collection, because you probably can not have dot in property name

Comment: The correct answer is: `db.orders.find({ "cart.items.isPremium": true })`